# How to use jQuery each() method within an append()

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have a function that adds a new row to a table. I also created a function that gets the value of text input with similar ids.

What I want to do is to append the collected values to the table, one on each column. The final column will contain a delete row link. I cant figure out how to do iteration (maybe an each method?) within an append method. Here is my code.

**Add Row Function**

```
$('.addrow').click(function(){
    $('.datatable > tbody:last-child')
     .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
            .append($('<a>')
                .attr('id', 'deleterow')
                .attr('href','#')
                .text('delete')
            )
        )
    );
});
```

**Delete Row Function**

```
$('.datatable').on('click', '.deleterow', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**Get Input Values Function**

```
$("input[class='textinput']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Comment: You don't put `.each` inside `.append`, you do it the other way around. Write a `.each()` loop, and the body appends another `<td>` to the `<tr>`.

Comment: And at the end, you append that `<tr>` to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code structure should be like this:

```
$("#addrow").click(function() {
    var new_row = $("<tr>");
    $("input.textinput").each(function() {
        new_row.append($("<td>", {
            text: $(this).val();
        });
    });
    new_row.append($("<td>").append($("<a>", {
        "class": "deleterow",
        "href": "#",
        "text": "delete"
    });
    $(".datatable tbody").append(new_row);
});
```

You loop over the data that you want to use to fill in the table columns, and in that loop you append each cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like so. In this scenario, for "each" element that has the class `.copy`, the code will run in the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".copy" ).each(function() {
      $("#target").append($(this).html());
    });
 });
```

Comment: To help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted problem